# Get Parent ID from SKU

Tags: programmatically, ee-1.13

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
require_once "app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();
umask(0);

try {

    echo('<h1>Completed Order Info</h1>');
    // M100210170 | M100210167 | M100210149 
    $orderId = '10006-L4'; // this is entity id 
    $order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

    // To get some basic order details, subtotal, shipping cost, discount, tax and grand total.

    echo "order number: ".$orderId."<br>";
    echo "order subtotal: ".$order->getSubtotal()."<br>";
    echo "shipping: ".$order->getShippingAmount()."<br>";
    echo "grand total: ".$order->getGrandTotal()."<br><br><br>";


    $orderItems = array();
    $getTotal=0;
    foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $item)
    {
        //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $parentIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getSku());
        echo "SKU = ".$item->getSku()."<br /># of Items in \$parentIds = ".count($parentIds)."<br />";
        if(count($parentIds)>0) {
            echo "<pre>\$parentIds<br />";
            echo print_r($parentIds);
            echo "</pre>";
        } else {
            echo "no items to return...<hr><br />";
        }

        $row=array();
        $row['sku'] = $item->getSku();
        $row['price'] = $item->getPrice();
        $row['qty_ordered']= (int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
        $row['subtotal']= (int)$row['qty_ordered'] * $row['price'];
        $row['item_total']= $item->getRowTotal();
        $getTotal = $getTotal + floatval(((int)$row['qty_ordered'] * $row['price']));    
        $orderItems[]=$row;
    }
    echo "\$getTotal = ".$getTotal."<br>";
    echo "All items in the order:<br><pre>".print_r($orderItems,true)."</pre><br><br><br>";

} catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
}
```

Comment: I need help getting the Parent ID from the child SKU. This is the line that is giving me problems:

    $parentIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getSku());

It doesn't return a value if I use the child Product ID or the SKU. Above is the full code that I'm using so far.

Comment: My apologies for the bad question formatting. I had to create an account and it kept most of my original post but not all of it and I didn't notice until after I posted it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getParentIdsByChild function needs id, not sku.

So try :

```
$parentIds = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($item->getId());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but it still returned no results. So even tho I had already tried getProductId() I tried it again and this time it returned a value, so thanks for steering me in the right direction. If someone can vote this up as helpful, I would appreciate it. I don't have enough reputation for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to see I help you :) You can accept the answer, it will be super for me !

Comment: I didn't see where to accept it as the answer initially, but I just accepted it now. Thanks again!

Comment: It's OK, you accept my answer, thank you and have a good day :)